# C# read only part of whole string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which has a following format:

```
"####/xxxxx"
```

The text before the "/" is always an integer and I need to read it. How do I get only the integer part of this string (before the "/")?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the methods available on string instances?

Comment: use String.Split to get the parts and Convert.ToInt32 to get the number. Or use SO search/Google...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the string on `/` and then use `int.TryParse` on the first element of array to see if it is an integer like:

```
string str = "1234/xxxxx";
string[] array = str.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int number = 0;
if (str.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(array[0], out number))
{
    //parsing successful. 
}
else
{
    //invalid number / string
}

Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
int indexOfSlash = text.IndexOf('/');
string beforeSlash = null;
int numBeforeSlash = int.MinValue;
if(indexOfSlash >= 0)
{
    beforeSlash = text.Substring(0, indexOfSlash);
    if(int.TryParse(beforeSlash, out numBeforeSlash))
    {
        // numBeforeSlash contains the real number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: use a regular expression:

```
var re = new System.Text.RegularExpression(@"^(\d+)/", RegexOptions.Compiled);
// ideally make re a static member so it only has to be compiled once

var m = re.Match(text);
if (m.IsMatch) {
  var beforeSlash = Integer.Parse(re.Groups[0].Value);
}
```